Docker compose weird issue can not pull images
I have tried to run "docker compose run -d" cmd on this docker file:
# DockerCompose-version 

# Define Services
services:

  # Eureka service
  eureka:
    image: ziedab/amsms-eureka-svc
    ports:
      - "8761:8761" 
    container_name: service_eureka_cont
    restart: always
    networks:
      - amsmicroservicesapp

  # Provider service
  provider:
    image: ziedab/amsms-provider-svc
    ports:
      - "8001:8001" 
    container_name: service_provider_cont
    depends_on:
      - dbprovider 
      - eureka
    restart: always
    environment:
        EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME: eureka
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://dbprovider:3306/bdServiceProviderAvril2024?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: provider
        SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: providerf7er7
    networks:
      - amsmicroservicesapp

  # Database Service Provider
  dbprovider:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: service_db_provider_cont
    volumes:
      - provider_db_data:/var/lib/mysql 
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bdServiceProviderAvril2024
      MYSQL_USER: provider
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: providerf7er7
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - amsmicroservicesapp

  # Article service
  article:
    image: ziedab/amsms-article-svc
    ports:
      - "8003:8003" 
    container_name: service_article_cont
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - dbarticle 
      - eureka
      - provider
    environment:
      EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME: eureka
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://dbarticle:3306/bdServiceArticleAvril2024?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: article
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: articlec87ef8
    networks:
      - amsmicroservicesapp

  # Database Service Provider
  dbarticle:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: service_db_article_cont
    volumes:
      - article_db_data:/var/lib/mysql 
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: bdServiceArticleAvril2024
      MYSQL_USER: article
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: articlec87ef8
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    networks:
      - amsmicroservicesapp

  # Proxy Service 
  proxy:
    image: serviceproxy
    container_name: ziedab/amsms-gateway-svc
    ports:
      - "9191:9191" 
    depends_on:
      - eureka
    restart: always
    environment:
      EUREKA_INSTANCE_HOSTNAME: eureka
    networks:
      - amsmicroservicesapp

  # PhpMyadmin Service 
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: service_pmadmin_cont
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - dbprovider
      - dbarticle
    ports:
      - 8077:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    networks:
      - amsmicroservicesapp

# Volume
volumes:
  provider_db_data:
  article_db_data:

# Network
networks:
  amsmicroservicesapp:

but, I obtained an "Error response from daemon: pull access denied" as shown in the image below:

when I pull then any image in the compose file, the pulling work fine as shown in the image below:

If I build my image and push it to dockerhub, it works also.
I tried to search in many websites and reads a lot of articles, but it seems few people encountered this problem.
I have also tried to uninstall and then reinstall my docker desktop. It doesn't work. i don't know what should i do?
By the way i use windows 10 machine

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including the error message, the docker-compose.yml, and any other required source code all in plain text?

  # Proxy Service 
  proxy:
    image: serviceproxy
    container_name: ziedab/amsms-gateway-svc

So your image reference is serviceproxy and name of container is  ziedab/amsms-gateway-svc? I bet you just swapped them by error

Yes, I see now what the error is. thanks for your help and time.
